# How to copy the template sites_enabled.j2 into a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default using adhoc commands. & How to start nginx using shell?

Tags: templates, nginx, ansible, adhoc, ansible-template

The template gets copied normally in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

On running this command: `ansible localhost -b -m copy -a "src=/abc/efg/ngs/templates/sites-enabled.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"`

The file gets copied.

`:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ls` gives the output as `default` & `sites-enabled.j2`.

How to copy the template provided in `/ngs` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and how to start the nginx using adhoc the commands?

Comment: you can check out `service module` from here but the better approach would be writing a `playbook` to do the above ad-hoc work PLUS starting the service as well. Here is the link for service module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/service_module.html

Answer (score 2):

**What I understood from your question is that:**

- You want to copy multiple template files from
  `src = "/abc/efg/ngs/"` to `dest = "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"`.
- You want to restart Nginx.

**To achieve this using Adhoc command:**

- COPY FILES: `ansible localhost -b -m copy -a "src=/abc/efg/ngs/templates dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/`
- START NGINX USING COMMAND MODULE: `ansible localhost -m command -a "systemctl start nginx"`
- START NGINX USING SHELL MODULE: `ansible localhost -m shell -a "systemctl start nginx"`

Ref to ad-hoc commands: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html

**To achieve this using the playbook command:**

```
- name: Copying files from source to destination
  copy:
    src: /abc/efg/ngs/templates
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: 0644
- name: Starting nginx
  command: systemctl start nginx
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/copy_module.html

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html

But rather I would suggest If you learn about handlers as they are very much helpful to do these kinds of tasks when you want to restart/reload any service only when a change happens.

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html

If you asked something else, let me know.